# Firebase Messaging - Can't receive notifications from subscriptions

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is the situation: I have a firebase cloud function that is running on every write to a certain database collection (called "jamrooms"). The NodeJS script is as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firebase Realtime Database.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.newJamroom = functions.database.ref('/jamrooms/{jamroomId}').onWrite(event => {

        // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        var jamroomId = event.params.jamroomId;

        var topic = "new-jamroom";
        var payload = {
            data: {
                title: "New jamroom available !",
                body: String("Jamroom id = ").concat(jamroomId)
            }
        };

        // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
        return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
                // contents of response.
                console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error sending message:", error);
            });
});
```

On the client side (Android), I've subscribed to the topic "new-jamroom":

```java
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("new-jamroom");
```

The script is successfully executed each time a new key-value pair is added to the collection:

[image]

but the client never receives the notification, either in background or in foreground.

I don't know where to look at to understand what's not going right.

**Update**

Even sending notifications from the console (using topic "new-jamroom", that exists in the console) doesn't send it to the client (Firebase records 0 sent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your payload contains the `data` key, you are sending a data-only message, not a notification:

```
    var payload = {
        data: {
            title: "New jamroom available !",
            body: String("Jamroom id = ").concat(jamroomId)
        }
```

Data messages and notification messages are [handled differently](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?authuser=0#notifications_and_data_messages) by the receiver.  Data-only messages cause `onMessageReceived()` to be invoked in the receiver.  To generate a notification, build your payload with the `notification` key:

```
    var payload = {
        notification: {  // <= CHANGED
            title: "New jamroom available !",
            body: String("Jamroom id = ").concat(jamroomId)
        }
```

Comment: Correct, I noticed it this afternoon. So, changing that made it work but not for my emulator, that is, a co-developer received the notification, but not me. I assume it is a configuration problem, but I don't know which one yet.

Comment: @ArthurDeschamps: Check your logcat for `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`. Your emulator may have an old version of Google Play services.

Comment: Actually I've also tried on my physical Android phone, and no notification neither. In either case, there is no such message in the logcat.

Comment: @ArthurDeschamps;  If the failing devices are API 26, it may be an issue with Notification Channels.

Comment: I've just received the notification.. but twice now. This is such a mess, but it seems to work now overall. Thanks for the help !